# which permissions an android application need in order to use the Alarm Manager Service?

Tags: android, permissions, alarm

If an android application wants to use the Alarm Manager Service, then which permissions the application needs to have?

I have tested that it seems that application does not need to have any permission to use the Alarm Manager Service.

Is that true?

Comment: do you think the 1st answer should be marked as correct?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is true. You do not have to add any special service. Keep in mind that when the handset is restarted the alarms you have set will be lost, so you may want to re-schedule them at boot time, which requires the `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Answer (score 9):

I dont know why not any one mention this permission

But according to android documentation , you should use SET_ALARM permission

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ALARM)

> Allows an application to broadcast an Intent to set an alarm for the
>   user.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: This is for the alarm clock, not for the AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**For more details :** [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: in my opinion it is not an (entire) solution, because you don't tell what happens if I don't use any permissions

Comment: Can you please explain why you are running the receiver in a remote process?

Answer (score 0):

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

code:

```
  package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
    }
```

If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I just did a test as your code, but I encountered an error: V/onPause:(10099): on pause
 V/updateReceiver(10099): update the apps
 D/AndroidRuntime(10099): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(10099): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(10099): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.tcm.alarm.intent.UPDATE flg=0x40000004 (has extras) } in com.tcm.alarm.AlarmActivity$updateReceiver@406ccfb0
 E/AndroidRuntime(10099):  at

Comment: why I could not input Enter to form the comment

Answer (score -2):

Would like to add few bits to what **Cristian** Said

Even if you use `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission your application will run properly on 2.X.X devices.

But in 4.x devices the broadvast receiver will not work on Boot until and unless you start application manually