# Set Alarm 8 clock in every day via android is not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am try to set Alarm 8am in every day to execute mainActivity , so this is my MainActivity:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      Intent Alarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LongRunningService.class);
      startService(Alarm);
   }
```

LongRunningService is Service :

```
   AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);   
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);   

   Intent i = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
   intent.setAction("startAlarm");
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,i,0);
   manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
     if ("startAlarm".equals(intent.getAction()))
         Log.d(TAG, "onReceive! ");  //not working?
    }
   Log.d(TAG, "onReceive! ");  //it's working
```

Comment: Did you add and request the permission?

Comment: @Angus Tay : <service android:name=".LongRunningService"/> and <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/> in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Typo: see self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: [which permissions an android application need in order to use the Alarm Manager Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237920/which-permissions-an-android-application-need-in-order-to-use-the-alarm-manager)

It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
```

...

**For more details :** [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

according to android documentation , you should use SET_ALARM permission

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ALARM)

> Allows an application to broadcast an Intent to set an alarm for the
>   user.

Answer (score 0):

I know what happen ,

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("startAlarm");  //wrong

    i.setAction("startAlarm");   //correct
```